# Java method that connects to SQL , what should I change localhost with so anyone can access my database?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

This is my method

```
 static void getHighScores() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "STUDENT", "STUDENT");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM HIGHSCORE ");
        System.out.println("Top Players");
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "  " + rs.getInt(2));
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e)

    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I have to change the @localhost part from my

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "STUDENT", "STUDENT");
```

With something so that anyone using the program would recive the list of HighScores.
What should I change it with?

Answer (score 1):

In your program you need only to change `localhost` with the ip of the machine running Oracle.

The biggest work is to ensure that external workstations can reach that ip and that the port is opened.

So you need to:

- Verify if that ip is reachable
- Verify that the port is open
- Verify that the configuration of oracle allow to join from an external IP.

Comment: Changed localhost to my IP , it works for me but when someone else uses it they get these errors
`Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

The weird thing is that after the error they get the list of highscores from my database which doesn't add their highscore but if I add one they can see my new highscore.

Comment: Check if it is possible to access the database using a client (Toad, SqlDeveloper, Tora, SqlPlus...). If you solve the access with a client you can access also from java

Answer (score 1):

If your code work correctly with only your local machine (the rest doesn't) then trouble come from your Oracle DB configuration.
About this, firstly, you should try to connect to your DB from another machine or through IP. If it's not success, then you should check your /etc/hosts file were edit to establish the connection over network yet. The syntax should follow as:

> [IP of your machine]   [full machine name with domain]        [machine name]

For example

> 127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
>   192.168.0.152   w2008-112-rac2.localdomain        w2008-112-rac2

Hope it help!